# How to select properties of arrays of indeterminate size (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, arrays, json, sql-server

I have a table of arrays, and would like to return a list of items.

```
| table                                 |
|---------------------------------------|
| [{"item": 1},{"item": 2},{"item": 3}] | 
| [{"item": 4},{"item": 5},{"item": 6}] |
| [{"item": 7},{"item": 8},{"item": 9}] |
```

**Example Query**

The following method will return a wide table of items, but it doesn't scale well.

```
select
json_value([table], '$[0].item'),
json_value([table], '$[1].item'),
json_value([table], '$[2].item')
from someTable;
```

How can I select properties of arrays of indeterminate size? (like 100)

**Desired Output**

```
| items |
|-------| 
| 1     | 
| 2     | 
| 3     | 
| 4     | 
| 5     | 
| 6     | 
| 7     | 
| 8     | 
| 9     |
```

Comment: Have you had a look at `OPENJSON`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `OPENJSON` to achieve this. Also, as I note, you should choose a different name than `Table` for a column's name. `TABLE` is a reserved key word and it's confusing as a `COLUMN` is not a `TABLE`.

```sql
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(N'[{"item": 1},{"item": 2},{"item": 3}]'), 
                (N'[{"item": 4},{"item": 5},{"item": 6}]'),
                (N'[{"item": 7},{"item": 8},{"item": 9}]'))V([Table])) --Table isn't a good choice of a came for a column.
                                                                       --TABLE is a reserved keyword.
SELECT T.item
FROM VTE V
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(V.[Table]) --Table isn't a good choice of a came for a column. TABLE is a reserved keyword.
                 WITH(item int) T;
```